# How to write new updated input name in print line in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to use this trigger to update the name of the staff on table staff, and then print the new name with a print line after updating, trigger works fine but I'm looking a way to write the name... any help?

```
CREATE TRIGGER EditNameStuff ON STAFF
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @editName CHAR, @ID_S INT

    SELECT @editName = DELETED.SNAME 
    FROM DELETED 
    WHERE STAFF_ID = DELETED.STAFF_ID;

    IF @editName != (SELECT inserted.SNAME 
                     FROM INSERTED 
                     WHERE STAFF_ID = inserted.STAFF_ID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @editName = STAFF_ID FROM INSERTED;

        UPDATE STAFF
        SET SNAME = @editName
        WHERE STAFF_ID = @ID_S ;

        PRINT 'Name has been succesfull changed to' [**Name should be here**] ;
    END
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT xx FROM Inserted WHERE ....` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: After you make this trigger set based, what are you expecting the PRINT statement to do? Surely your users are not using the database directly? As such that PRINT statement is not going to do anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: marc_s is right about avoiding cursors. They're very resource-intensive. If the your goal is to use a trigger to print your output, you can build a string to print, stick it in a variable, and then print the variable's value. Because multiple rows can be updated at a time, and the trigger will handle all rows at once, you can use STUFF and FOR XML PATH to basically build a line-carriage delimited list of statements for each update. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON dbo.Staff
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @output = STUFF((SELECT CHAR(10) + 'Name has been changed to ' + ISNULL(SNAME, 'NULL') + ' where STAFF_ID = ' + CAST(STAFF_ID AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM INSERTED i
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')

    PRINT @output
END
GO
```

Here's a cursor-based solution, which again, is best to avoid unless this is a lightly-updated table, and it's likely to scale to a heavily-updated table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON dbo.Staff
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @STAFF_ID INT, @ORIG_SNAME VARCHAR(100), @NEW_SNAME VARCHAR(100)

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR   
    SELECT i.STAFF_ID, d.SNAME, i.SNAME
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.STAFF_ID = d.STAFF_ID
    WHERE (d.SNAME IS NULL AND i.SNAME IS NOT NULL) OR (d.SNAME IS NOT NULL AND i.SNAME IS NULL) OR d.SNAME <> i.SNAME

    OPEN cur  

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
    INTO @STAFF_ID, @ORIG_SNAME, @NEW_SNAME

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   
        -- custom code goes here!
        PRINT 'Name has been changed to ' + ISNULL(@NEW_SNAME, 'NULL') + ' where STAFF_ID = ' + CAST(@STAFF_ID AS VARCHAR(10))

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
        INTO @STAFF_ID, @ORIG_SNAME, @NEW_SNAME
    END   
    CLOSE cur;  
    DEALLOCATE cur;  
END
GO
```

Comment: You should **AVOID** cursors at all costs (because they are RBAR processing - row-by-agonizing-row) - **MOST DEFINITELY** inside a trigger! This is going to **KILL** all your system performance - seriously --  ***DO NOT DO THIS!*** You need to turn this into a **proper, set-based** solution

Comment: @marc_s is generally correct about avoiding cursors! They're slow and resource-intensive. Though, I hate absolute statements like that. This won't KILL your system performance unless this is a table that is heavily used and frequently updated. However, if it is updated regularly, or you anticipate it may scale that way, yes, you should avoid using a cursor.